# Python - if else - program flow

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written a multiple choice program, which is not behaving the way I expect.

I want it to behave this way -

1. When you type 1, to go to the block below #USD and
2. When you type 2, it  should go to the block below #Euro

***Here Is My Code:***

```
print "Welcome to Currency Converter By Fend Artz"
print "your options are:"
print " "
print "1) GDP -> USD"
print "2) GDP -> Euro"
USD = int(raw_input(''))
if USD == 1:
    choice = USDchoice    
elif USD == 2:
    choice = EUROchoice
else:
    print ("You have to put a number 1 or 2")
    int(raw_input(''))
#USD
def USDchoice():
    userUSD = float(input('How many pounds do you want to convert?(e.g. 5)\n'))
    USD = userUSD * 0.65
    print userUSD, "Pounds =",USD,"USDs"

#Euro
def EUROchoice():
    userEURO = float(input('How many pounds do you want to convert?(e.g. 5)\n'))
    Euro = userEURO * 1.37 
    print userEURO, "Pounds =",Euro,"Euros"

#Thing so the script doesn't instantly close
Enter = raw_input('press ENTER to close\n')
```

Comment: choice = USDchoice()

Comment: you are setting `choice` to the function but you are not calling it.

Comment: add the () to make it call the function.

Comment: when calling function do it like this `USDchoice()`

Comment: What the above comments said, plus you will have to move your two functions above your main code so your function calls will be recognized by the interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things wrong with the code.

1. You set the variable `choice` to be a reference to your one of your functions: `USDChoice` or `EUROChoice`. You need to *call* these functions, setting the variable equal to the value that they return, using parentheses. As several comments have pointed out, you do this like `USDChoice()` and `EUROChoice()`.
2. You try to call the functions before they're created. They need to be moved above, because everything is in the global scope (module-level).

Fixed code:

```
#USD
def USDchoice():
    userUSD = float(input('How many pounds do you want to convert?(e.g. 5)\n'))
    USD = userUSD * 0.65
    print userUSD, "Pounds =",USD,"USDs"


#Euro
def EUROchoice():
    userEURO = float(input('How many pounds do you want to convert?(e.g. 5)\n'))
    Euro = userEURO * 1.37 
    print userEURO, "Pounds =",Euro,"Euros"


print "Welcome to Currency Converter By Fend Artz"
print "your options are:"
print " "
print "1) GDP -> USD"
print "2) GDP -> Euro"
USD = int(raw_input(''))

if USD == 1:
    choice = USDchoice()
elif USD == 2:
    choice = EUROchoice()
else:
    print ("You have to put a number 1 or 2")
    int(raw_input(''))

#Thing so the script doesn't instantly close
Enter = raw_input('press ENTER to close\n')
```

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH very helpful :D